# How to reduce the font size in ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My app currency converter update the result each time you add or remove a number in the input (event onChange).

The  problem is the size of the result increase if you add some numbers, so I want to change the font size if needed. (bigger or smaller depends)

[image: no overflow]
[image: overflow]

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think when I make a new render(), I will count the characters, and change the font-size according to the length of my string.

I calculate my new font-size like that :

```
newSize = parseInt(400/res.length);
```

And in the JSX render, I did this :

```js
<div className='overflow' id="result" style={{fontSize: newSize+'px'}}>
    {res}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to initiate your state :

```
const[isBig,setIsBig()] = React.useState(false);
```

after that, you need to check the size of the result and depends on the size of your output update isBig ( your state )

and that's it, if isBig true set the fontSize :12px else 15px or I don't know depends on your needs:

```
<span style={isBig ? {fontSize:'12px'} : {fontSize:'15px'}}>your resulsts here </span>
```

Comment: You haven't explained how to determine when `isBig` should be set to `true`

Comment: `12` and `15` are not valid values for the CSS `font-size` property.

Comment: Please read the formatting instructions next to the question editor. You have marked almost everything as bold text (making it hard to read) and none of the code as code.